# Three rewrite rules for one location different conditions

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect the URLs starting with same word on the account of the parameters it has. Simply look at the code of mine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+) /$1.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?ref=$3
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?refsub=$4
```

If URL is like `/products/xyz` I want this to be redirected to `/xyz.php`

If URL is like `/products/xyz/abc/11` I want this to be redirected to `xyz.php?ref=11`

And  if URL is like `/products/xyz/abc/def/111` I want this to be redirected to `xyz.php?refsub=111`

I've tried with the code & it's not working. Any flaw in this? Can anyone help?

Comment: For a start, you just need one `RewriteEngine On` command. Once it's on, it's on

Comment: Okay accepted, can you share a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that all routes match the first one, so they'll all stop there. You can either reverse-order them, so they have to match the most-explicit route first:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?refsub=$4
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?ref=$3
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+) /$1.php
```

Or you could just add end-of-URL markers:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?ref=$3
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?refsub=$4
```

Comment: Perfect, foolish mistake. Done, thanks a lot for quick response :)